# Running Mocha with Node.js v8.10.0

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to run Mocha (version 8.0.1) with Node (version 8.10.0) and I keep getting this error:

mocha test:
`-bash: mocha: command not found`

npm test:

```
return import(url.pathToFileURL(file));
           ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/SWS/notification-system/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:18:27)
```

My guess is that this Node version might be incompatible with mocha.

What can I do to run mocha with my current Node version?
I tried running with *experimental-options*, but no luck yet (maybe I am not doing it right)!

Answer (score 0):

Your node version doesn't recognize `import` since it doesn't support `ES6`.

Consider using `require` instead of `import`.
You can also use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

**EDIT**

Since the error comes from the mocha package, you will need to upgrade `NodeJS` or downgrade `mocha`. Thats because [mocha version v8.0.0 requires Node.js version v10.12.0 or newer](https://mochajs.org/#installation).

Comment: That is inside the Mocha library that I am using. It's not my code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't.

Comment: So I think you can't use this version of mocha.. you'll need to install an earlier version of it. The documentation says `As of v8.0.0, Mocha requires Node.js v10.12.0 or newer.`. Here: https://mochajs.org/#installation